# make kml layer from a string (GWT)

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, kml

I have a KML in the form of a string. Actually I call a service from my GWT project and the service returns a KML file in the form of a string. How can I present this KML on my map? All I have is a string. Should I first parse it or can I create a KML layer from this string?

//I'm using google maps v3 api for GWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you were working in JavaScript, but since you are working in Java, have you taken a look at the [JAK Java API for KML](http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/)? It uses JAXB under the covers, but it provides an `unmarshal` function that accepts either a file or a `String`. There is an [article describing the library on TheServerSide.com](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=57055) and another article on [Java.net](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/thlandgraf/archive/2009/08/java_api_for_km.html).

And finally, there is some good and detailed documentation available at [Micromata's JAK site](http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home). Hope this helps -

Comment: Thank you, but this is for JS and I can't use it in Google Web Toolkit. Furthermore it doesn't support polygons, which is my main target.

Comment: Thought you were using JS. I've updated my answer above, switched over to focus on Java.

Comment: I've seen this API but I didn't quite understand the correct way to use it. Probably this is the only way to do what I want to do. I'll take a closer look. Thnx!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the exact same thing you are. Check out this example from Google: [KmlOverlayDemo.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/maps/samples/hellomaps/src/com/google/gwt/maps/sample/hellomaps/client/KmlOverlayDemo.java?r=1715).

You will have to write the string to a file (this would be best done on the server side) and then call `GeoXmlOverlay.load("KmlFilePath", GeoXmlLoadCallback)`. If successful, an overlay object is returned that you can just add to the `MapWidget`.

This is the best way I've found so far, but I'm searching for a better way.